# tftp server on minikube connection not working

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, tftp

I'm in the process of converting my docker-compose setup to minikube, this is the first time I'm using minikube/kubernetes so might be something obvious

One of my docker images was a tftp server for a pxe boot.
I'm trying to get the UDP port forwarding working but not having much success.

Got minikube running with the ingress addon enabled and the following config:

deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: pxe
  name: pxe
  namespace: home
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pxe
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pxe
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: pxe-storage
        hostPath:
          path: /storage/pxe/tftp
          type: Directory
      containers:
      - image: pghalliday/tftp:latest
        name: pxe
        ports:
        - containerPort: 69
          protocol: UDP
          name: pxe
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pxe-storage
          mountPath: /var/tftpboot
```

service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pxe
  namespace: home
spec:
  selector:
    app: pxe
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: udp-port
      port: 69
      targetPort: 69
      protocol: UDP
```

ingress patch:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: controller
        ports:
         - containerPort: 69
           hostPort: 69
           protocol: UDP
```

Doing the following:

```
kubectl create namespace home
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f service.yaml
kubectl patch configmap udp-services -n kube-system --patch '{"data":{"69":"home/pxe:69"}}'
kubectl patch deployment ingress-nginx-controller --patch "$(cat patch.yaml)" -n kube-system
```

Connection never works:

```
$ tftp `minikube ip`
tftp> get test.txt
Transfer timed out.
```

The tftp server pod does work, can access it from within the cluster:

```
$ minikube ssh
$ $ tftp -g -r test.txt  172.17.0.2
tftp: server error: (1) File not found
```

---

Edit:

In response to @mario his questions:

Did modify the patch to include the protocol as by default it was TCP and should have been UDP, but even after the change no luck :(

```
$ kubectl get configmaps udp-services -o yaml -n kube-system
apiVersion: v1
data:
  "69": home/pxe:69
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"EnsureExists"},"name":"udp-services","namespace":"kube-system"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2020-12-17T16:30:41Z"
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: {}
    manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-12-17T16:30:41Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:data:
        .: {}
        f:69: {}
    manager: kubectl-patch
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-12-17T16:31:58Z"
  name: udp-services
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "601"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/udp-services
  uid: c913188f-3390-4b09-a1ab-e2f4105744fa
```

Hope this isn't too long:

```
$ kubectl get deployment ingress-nginx-controller -o yaml -n kube-system
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "3"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile","app.kubernetes.io/component":"controller","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/part-of":"kube-system"},"name":"ingress-nginx-controller","namespace":"kube-system"},"spec":{"replicas":1,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"controller","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx"}},"strategy":{"rollingUpdate":{"maxSurge":1,"maxUnavailable":1},"type":"RollingUpdate"},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile","app.kubernetes.io/component":"controller","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx","gcp-auth-skip-secret":"true"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"args":["/nginx-ingress-controller","--configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-load-balancer-conf","--report-node-internal-ip-address","--tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services","--udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services","--validating-webhook=:8443","--validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert","--validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key"],"env":[{"name":"POD_NAME","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.name"}}},{"name":"POD_NAMESPACE","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.namespace"}}}],"image":"us.gcr.io/k8s-artifacts-prod/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.40.2","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","lifecycle":{"preStop":{"exec":{"command":["/wait-shutdown"]}}},"livenessProbe":{"failureThreshold":3,"httpGet":{"path":"/healthz","port":10254,"scheme":"HTTP"},"initialDelaySeconds":10,"periodSeconds":10,"successThreshold":1,"timeoutSeconds":1},"name":"controller","ports":[{"containerPort":80,"hostPort":80,"name":"http","protocol":"TCP"},{"containerPort":443,"hostPort":443,"name":"https","protocol":"TCP"},{"containerPort":8443,"name":"webhook","protocol":"TCP"}],"readinessProbe":{"failureThreshold":3,"httpGet":{"path":"/healthz","port":10254,"scheme":"HTTP"},"initialDelaySeconds":10,"successThreshold":1,"timeoutSeconds":1},"resources":{"requests":{"cpu":"100m","memory":"90Mi"}},"securityContext":{"allowPrivilegeEscalation":true,"capabilities":{"add":["NET_BIND_SERVICE"],"drop":["ALL"]},"runAsUser":101},"volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/usr/local/certificates/","name":"webhook-cert","readOnly":true}]}],"serviceAccountName":"ingress-nginx","volumes":[{"name":"webhook-cert","secret":{"secretName":"ingress-nginx-admission"}}]}}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2020-12-17T16:30:41Z"
  generation: 3
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-system
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/component: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/part-of: {}
      f:spec:
        f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
        f:selector:
          f:matchLabels:
            .: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/component: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
        f:strategy:
          f:rollingUpdate:
            .: {}
            f:maxSurge: {}
            f:maxUnavailable: {}
          f:type: {}
        f:template:
          f:metadata:
            f:labels:
              .: {}
              f:addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: {}
              f:app.kubernetes.io/component: {}
              f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
              f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
              f:gcp-auth-skip-secret: {}
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"controller"}:
                .: {}
                f:args: {}
                f:env:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"name":"POD_NAME"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:valueFrom:
                      .: {}
                      f:fieldRef:
                        .: {}
                        f:apiVersion: {}
                        f:fieldPath: {}
                  k:{"name":"POD_NAMESPACE"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:valueFrom:
                      .: {}
                      f:fieldRef:
                        .: {}
                        f:apiVersion: {}
                        f:fieldPath: {}
                f:image: {}
                f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                f:lifecycle:
                  .: {}
                  f:preStop:
                    .: {}
                    f:exec:
                      .: {}
                      f:command: {}
                f:livenessProbe:
                  .: {}
                  f:failureThreshold: {}
                  f:httpGet:
                    .: {}
                    f:path: {}
                    f:port: {}
                    f:scheme: {}
                  f:initialDelaySeconds: {}
                  f:periodSeconds: {}
                  f:successThreshold: {}
                  f:timeoutSeconds: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:ports:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"containerPort":80,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:containerPort: {}
                    f:hostPort: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:protocol: {}
                  k:{"containerPort":443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:containerPort: {}
                    f:hostPort: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:protocol: {}
                  k:{"containerPort":8443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:containerPort: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:protocol: {}
                f:readinessProbe:
                  .: {}
                  f:failureThreshold: {}
                  f:httpGet:
                    .: {}
                    f:path: {}
                    f:port: {}
                    f:scheme: {}
                  f:initialDelaySeconds: {}
                  f:periodSeconds: {}
                  f:successThreshold: {}
                  f:timeoutSeconds: {}
                f:resources:
                  .: {}
                  f:requests:
                    .: {}
                    f:cpu: {}
                    f:memory: {}
                f:securityContext:
                  .: {}
                  f:allowPrivilegeEscalation: {}
                  f:capabilities:
                    .: {}
                    f:add: {}
                    f:drop: {}
                  f:runAsUser: {}
                f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
                f:volumeMounts:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"mountPath":"/usr/local/certificates/"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:mountPath: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:readOnly: {}
            f:dnsPolicy: {}
            f:restartPolicy: {}
            f:schedulerName: {}
            f:securityContext: {}
            f:serviceAccount: {}
            f:serviceAccountName: {}
            f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
            f:volumes:
              .: {}
              k:{"name":"webhook-cert"}:
                .: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:secret:
                  .: {}
                  f:defaultMode: {}
                  f:secretName: {}
    manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-12-17T16:30:41Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: {}
      f:status:
        f:conditions:
          .: {}
          k:{"type":"Available"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
        f:observedGeneration: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:unavailableReplicas: {}
        f:updatedReplicas: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-12-17T16:42:08Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:template:
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"controller"}:
                f:ports:
                  k:{"containerPort":69,"protocol":"UDP"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:containerPort: {}
                    f:hostPort: {}
                    f:protocol: {}
    manager: kubectl-patch
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-12-17T16:42:08Z"
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "1178"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments/ingress-nginx-controller
  uid: cfead3f0-f9ae-4887-a4fe-5741a8681e39
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        gcp-auth-skip-secret: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-load-balancer-conf
        - --report-node-internal-ip-address
        - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
        - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
        - --validating-webhook=:8443
        - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
        - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: us.gcr.io/k8s-artifacts-prod/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.40.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - /wait-shutdown
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: controller
        ports:
        - containerPort: 69
          hostPort: 69
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: webhook
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 90Mi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          capabilities:
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            drop:
            - ALL
          runAsUser: 101
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
          name: webhook-cert
          readOnly: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: ingress-nginx
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: webhook-cert
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2020-12-17T16:30:41Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2020-12-17T16:30:41Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2020-12-17T16:30:41Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2020-12-17T16:42:08Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "ingress-nginx-controller-c9b778c5c" is progressing.
    reason: ReplicaSetUpdated
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 3
  replicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

Comment: Could you share the result of `kubectl get configmaps udp-services -o yaml` after patching it as well as `kubectl get deployment ingress-nginx-controller -o yaml` ?

Comment: Added the information, did notice one wrong thing that I've fixed and that is the patch didn't include the udp protocol, but even after the change still no luck :(

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ? Does it have to be exposed via `ingress` ? Could you try first to expose it via a [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) service ? Does this work ?

Comment: Did not get it working, moved the tftp server to a synology nas where it worked right away. This was for a PXE boot so only required a single file